# "useDispatch" is not dispatching action on clicking button

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

while working with react-redux , i am unable to dispatch an action called "profileUpdateAction" on button click and i cant figure out why. there is no error in console and redux-devtools shows nothing on clicking button.I have implemented same thing in other components but unable to here for some reason . please help.

[image: nothing on redux devtools on clicking]

**profileEdit.js -**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { profileUpdateAction } from "../Redux/actions/profileActions";

const ProfileEdit = ({ history }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const updateProfile = useSelector((state) => state.updateProfile);
  const { success } = updateProfile;
const [profileDetails, setprofileDetails] = useState({status:""});

 const change = (e) => {
    setprofileDetails({ status: e.target.value });
  };


  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(profileUpdateAction(profileDetails));
    console.log("submit function & success=" + success);
}

return (
    <>
<input type="text" name='status' value={profileDetails} onChange={(e) => change(e)}/>
<button onClick={(e) => submitHandler(e)}>update</button>
</>
)}
```

the console log above produces output as - `submit function & success=undefined`

**profileAction.js -**

```
export const profileUpdateAction = (profileDetails) => async (
  getState,
  dispatch
) => {

  try {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE_REQ,
    });

    const {
      logging: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        authorization: `bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.put(`api/profile`,profileDetails, config);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
    localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
      payload: error,
    });
   
  }

};
```

**ActionReducer.js -**

```
export const updateProfileReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_PROFILE_REQ:
      return { ...state, loading: true, success: false };
    case UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, profile: payload, success: true };
    case UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: payload, success: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

the reducer has been added to "combineReducers" in **store.js** , also the component has been wrapped under "Provider " in **app.js** where i am rendering all components

Comment: Switch the order of ```getState``` and ```dispatch``` in the function returned from the ```profileUpdateAction``` action creator. I'm pretty sure ```dispatch``` meant to be the first argument and ```getState``` second...

Comment: thank you very much . This was it . Never forgetting this again

Comment: Sweet, glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try put types(UPDATE_PROFILE_REQ, UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS, UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL) as a string("UPDATE_PROFILE_REQ", "UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS", "UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL") in action and in reducer.

Comment: i dont think this is an issue , i am importing constants from other components . it was the order of "dispatch" and "getState" as @kyle Lambert pointed out